# SQL Statement and Prepared Statement error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, inner-join

The user inputs a disease and the SQL is supposed to return all patient details who have the disease. But i'm getting the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

SQL Query is as shown below. Please help me to debug it.

```
SELECT patient_personal_details.patient_id, 
       patient_personal_details.first_name, 
       patient_personal_details.last_name, 
       patient_personal_details.gender, 
       patient_personal_details.occupation, 
       patient_personal_details.marital_status 
FROM patient_personal_details
INNER JOIN patient_medical_details
ON patient_personal_details.patient_id = patient_medical_details.patient_id
WHERE patient_medical_details.disease = ?
```

Here's the code:

```
public JTable getAllPatientsByDisease(String disease)throws RemoteException{
    JTable table = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hospital_database","root","");
        String sql = " SELECT patient_personal_details.patient_id, patient_personal_details.first_name, patient_personal_details.last_name, patient_personal_details.gender, patient_personal_details.occupation, patient_personal_details.marital_status FROM patient_personal_details "
                + " INNER JOIN patient_medical_details "
                + " ON patient_personal_details.patient_id = patient_medical_details.patient_id "
                + " WHERE patient_medical_details.disease = ? ";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, disease);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);

        table =  new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));
    }
    catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: And where is the code that executes this query?

Comment: Eran please see below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**: *(now we have the code)*

The problem is here:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);
// ----------------------------^^^
```

Remove the `sql`, just use:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

By specifying the SQL as an argument, you were using [`Statement#executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-), not [`PreparedStatement#executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--). `Statement#executeQuery` uses the SQL string literally, without substituting in the parameters (basically as though you'd not called `setString`). (And yes, it's not a fantastic design decision by the JDBC folks.)

---

**Original Answer**:

The key bit of that error message is *"...near '?'"* That tells us that you never set a value to be substituted into the query at that point, and so the ? was used literally.

You need to use [`setString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-) (if the "disease" column is a textual column) or `setInt`, etc., to set the parameters for the query. E.g.:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT ... WHERE patient_medical_details.disease = ?");
ps.setString(1, "arachnophobia"); // <===
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

The parameters are numbered (somewhat surprisingly) starting with 1 for the first `?`, 2 for the second, etc.